# jQuery Ajax load function +returning a value other than the HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I am using the following jQuery code to fill my DIV in the ASPX page

```
   var div = $("#divPrice");  
   div.fadeOut('slow',function(){      
   div.load("../Lib/handlers/GetPrice.aspx?answers="+queryValues+"&item="+modelId,{ symbol: $("#txtSymbol" ).val() },function()
   {
      $(this).fadeIn('slow');                                           
   });

   });   
  $("#divBtns").fadeIn('slow');
```

This works fine. In Get `price.aspx`, it will return a HTML and it will be loaded in the div.
Now i want to return another number along with this HTML to my javascript. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please read [these](http://encosia.com/category/jquery/) posts to get in depth knowledge about using jquery to play with asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

use hidden control input to do that :

asp.net

```
<input type="hidden" id="yr_control" value="<%=Request.QueryString.Get("val_control") %>" />
```

code behind:

```
Request.QueryString.Get("val_control")
```

in ajax

```
$("#yr_control").attr("value")
```